# Presentations of PSL(2, Z/p^n)

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-groups, presentations-of-groups

As is well known, the group $PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$ is isomorphic to the free product $C_2 \ast C_3$ of cyclic groups of order $2$ and $3$. Call the generators of the cyclic groups $S$ and $T$.

> **Problem:** Given a prime number $p$ and a natural number $n$, write a presentation of the quotient $PSL(2, \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb  Z)$ with the images of $S$ and $T$ as generators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually use [Sunday's](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1972-118-x) presentation: see [MR0311782](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0311782).  His T has order 2 but your S will be what he denotes ST.

Comment: A direct link with no proxy: http://math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1972-118-x

Answer (score 7):

A method to do this for the group $\textrm{PSL}_2 (\mathbb{F}_{p^n})$ can be found in the papers by Glover and Sjerve:

[Representing $PSl_2(p)$ on a Riemann surface of least genus](http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-54572), L'Enseignement Mathématique **31** (1985)

[The genus of $PSl_2(q)$](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0380&DMDID=dmdlog7), Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik **380** (1987).

Comment: For some reason I cannot put the correct link to the first paper. Anyway, it is available for free download: just go to http://www.unige.ch/math/EnsMath/EM_en/welcome.html
and follow the link to the left at the bottom of the page

Comment: From the information on the linked website, it seems that the link http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-54572 should be persistent.

Answer (score 4):

The group $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^n)$ is the automorphisms group of the $(p+1)$ regular tree of depth $n$, where at level $m$ of the tree you have the points of $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{Z}/p^m)$. The main benefit of this view, is that you can understand the relations at each level, and then move inductively to the next one.