# $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^n)$ isomorphic to automorphism group of depth-$n$, $(p+1)$-regular tree?

Tags: gr.group-theory, automorphism-groups

A comment on another question (linked below) states

"The group $PSL_2((\mathbb{Z}/p^n))$ is the automorphisms group of the $(p+1)$ regular tree of depth $n$, where at level $m$ of the tree you have the points of $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{Z}/p^m)$."

I was unable to find a reference stating this.  Is it true, and if so what is the correct reference?

Comment: [Presentations of PSL(2, Z/p^n)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79197/presentations-of-psl2-z-pn/79240#79240)

Comment: Isn't this already false for $n=1$ where for $T$ the $(p+1)$-regular tree of depth 1, $Aut(T)$ is $S_{p+1}$ which is not isomorphic to $PSL(2,p)$ unless $p=2$?

Comment: Yes you appear to be correct. I wonder if the person who wrote that was completely off base, or if something along these lines is true...

Comment: Note that the finite group in the header would usually be interpreted as the points over a finite field of order $p^n$ rather than over the finite ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$.   A little more care with the notation is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, the group $G=PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^n)$ is not the full automorphism group of the $(p+1)$-regular tree of depth $n$. These particular groups of automorphisms have quite some additional structure.

For example, if one fixes any leaf $x$, then the point-stabilizer $G_x$ contains a normal subgroup $U_x$ which works regular on the leaves which are not in the same branch as $x$ (i.e. the leaves $y$ for which the path fro $x$ to $y$ passes the root of the tree). In this particular case, the groups $U_x$ will be isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/p^n$.

Answer (score 2):

For much more than you ever wanted, see Serre's Trees, Chapter II.